# Blackberry 10 - running app in background

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-qnx

On the new blackberry 10 platform how can one develop a VoIP application which needs to contact a server every 10 minutes or so and receive incoming calls. I think there is no 
option for background service like Android platform. Can the app be left running by the user, if so can the user start new apps like email etc without stopping an existing app.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run BlackBerry 10 applications in the background, no problem at all. All you need to do is include the `<permission>run_when_backgrounded</permission>` in your `bar-descriptor.xml`. This makes the user aware that your app needs to run in the background and allows them to approve or deny it.

Check out: https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/dev/fundamentals/index.html for more.